# Ranking System in PHP and SQL (A+, B, C etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

My question is about how to make a ranking system in where for example, 1000-1199 points is Rank C, while 1200-1299 is Rank C+, and also multiple people can get the same rank if they are hovering around those points?

I haven't tried any code yet as I have no idea how to start this and has been searching my ass off for any clue or idea to do it online, and the only thing I know was how to rank them from example 1-10 in a decreasing manner on a table which was this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr>
            <td>{$rank}</td>
            <td>{$row['firstName']} </td>
            <td>{$row['score']}</td>
            <td> </td>
                </tr>";
                $rank++;
            }
        }
```

inside a php.

The one at the top though is entirely different to what I want.

Any Ideas would be great, I've been looking on group by function but it kind of is different in sql.

Thanks

Comment: how about something among the lines of `if($row['score'] >= 1000 && $row['score'] < 1200) { $rank = 'C'; }`? seriously, you should have at least pretended to try.

Comment: how many ranks are there? also add if else to achieve that (inside while).And `$rank++;` is seems to be disaster there.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like I was joking/seeking direct answer but I am serious about this. Thanks for the answer though, I kind of shy'd away from using the if statement in the php file and was wondering if there was a way to actually store it through using sql statements..

Comment: @bbnjo8  why don't you add one more column something like `rank_garde` and directly store value there like `A,B,C,C+`  at the time when you are inserting record of the user (more easy). If not possible then i will recommend to use `if/else` instead of creating a very complex query.

Comment: @AlivetoDie there would be multiple ranks from C- to A+, and points will consider to where they are ranked. The one I posted is a different idea to what I really want, as that is for showing in a table to what number the person is in the leaderboards based on their score. Thanks

Comment: @AlivetoDie I would do what you suggest but then their rank changes as they play as they may increase or decrease their points. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I would implement such a banding via sql, not via php code.

I would create a table to hold the band configuration (lets call it `score_bands`):

- band name (char, not null) to hold the name of the band (sample values: A+, A , etc.)
- lower limit (integer, not null, default 0) to hold the lower limit for the band
  -upper limit (integer, not null, default 0) to hold the upper limit for the band

When you query your users, you can join using their score to find out which band they are. I assume that your `users` table has a column called `score` that holds the score of the user based on which you want to assign a band:

```
select u.*, b.band_name
from users u
left join score_bands b on u.score>=b.lower_limit and u.score<=b.upper_limit
```

You have to make sure that the band score ranges do not overlap, otherwise a user may be classified into multiple bands.

The advantage of this solution is its flexibility. You can very easily redefine the bands by changing the limits in the band configuration table, and adding or removing records from the same table. Any changes to the limits are automatically visible when you next perform a query with the join. No complicated `if` or `case` (`switch`) structures are involved.